# How to make link clickable in Spring Hateos

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

I have a spring application which is using spring hateos which show the documents in the below format.

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "employee" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/employee"
    },
    "address" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/address"
    },
    "company" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/company"
    }
  }
}
```

So is there any way we can make href link clickable so that rather than copying the resources link in new window and then accessing the resources instead of that we can directly click on the link and access the resource.
Please help on this

Comment: Where are you displaying the JSON ? It is what is displaying the JSON that should support this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understand that it is a `JSON` object, which is a plain JavaScript Object Notation and is generally evaluated within a JavaScript code only.

If you really want to make these links click-able in your browser then you need to render this `JSON` into your `HTML`. In other words, you need to take this `JSON` out of your javascript and bring it to HTML where you can add anchor `<a>` tags around it.

[JSON2HTML](http://json2html.com/) is one of the templating library which can be of use to you.

Code snippet for your use below:

HTML

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Bob (40)</li>
    <li>Frank (15)</li>
    <li>Bill (65)</li>
    <li>Robert (24)</li>
</ul>
```

And the script

```
var transform = {'tag':'li','html':'${name} (${age})'};

var data = [
    {'name':'Bob','age':40},
    {'name':'Frank','age':15},
    {'name':'Bill','age':65},
    {'name':'Robert','age':24}
];

json2html.transform(data,transform);
```